# Internal server error (500) httpwebrequest

Tags: httpwebrequest, system.net.webexception

> System.Net.WebException: The remote
>   server returned an error: (500)
>   Internal Server Error. at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>   at
>   refill.btnRequestRefill_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)

I get this error when trying to submit a form. Here is my code:

```
Protected Sub btnRequestRefill_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRequestRefill.Click

    Try
        Dim url As String = "www.domainname.com"

        url += "lastName=" & LastName.Text
        url += "&birthDate=" & Birthdate.Text
        url += "&RxNumbers=" & RxNumber.Text
        url += "&deliveryMethod=" & deliverymethod.SelectedValue
        url += "&phone=" & PhoneNumber.Text
        url += "&email=" & Email.Text

        Dim myrequest As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)

        Dim docresponse As WebResponse = myrequest.GetResponse()
        Dim responsestream As Stream = docresponse.GetResponseStream()
        Dim objXMLDoc As New XmlDocument()
        Dim colElements As XmlNodeList
        Dim colElements2 As XmlNodeList
        Dim mywebclient As New WebClient()
        Dim a As Object
        Dim listingscount As Integer = 0

        objXMLDoc.Load(responsestream)
        colElements = objXMLDoc.GetElementsByTagName("script")

        For Each objnode As XmlNode In colElements
            Dim attCol As XmlAttributeCollection = objnode.Attributes

            If objnode.Name = "script" Then
                If attCol(0).Value = "false" Then
                    colElements2 = objXMLDoc.GetElementsByTagName("rxResponse")
                    For Each objnode2 As XmlNode In colElements2
                        Response.Write("<br/>" & objnode2.InnerText & "<br/>")
                    Next
                Else
                    Response.Write("<br/>yay it when through<br/>")

                    Dim redir, mailto, mailfrom, subject, item, body, cc, bcc, message, html, template, usetemplate, testmode
                    subject = "Refill Submit - test"

                    usetemplate = False

                    Dim msg = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
                    msg.subject = subject
                    msg.to = "name@domainname.com,name@domainname.com,name@domainname.com"
                    msg.from = "name@domainname.com"

                    For Each item In Request.Form
                        Select Case item
                            Case "redirect", "mailto", "cc", "bcc", "subject", "message", "template", "html", "testmode", "__EVENTTARGET", "__EVENTARGUMENT", "__VIEWSTATE", "__EVENTVALIDATION", "btnRequestRefill","__LASTFOCUS"
                            Case Else
                                If Not usetemplate Then
                                    If item <> "mailfrom" Then body = body & item & ": " & Request.Form(item) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                                Else
                                    body = Replace(body, "[$" & item & "$]", Replace(Request.Form(item), vbCrLf, "<br>"))
                                End If
                        End Select
                    Next

                    If usetemplate Then 'remove any leftover placeholders
                        Dim rx As New Regex("\[\$.*\$\]")
                        body = rx.Replace(body, "")
                    End If

                    If usetemplate And LCase(Request.Form("html")) = "yes" Then
                        msg.htmlbody = body
                    Else
                        msg.textbody = body
                    End If

                    msg.send()
                    msg = Nothing
                End If
            Else
                Response.Write("<br/>" & "not script" & "<br/>")
            End If
            'Response.Write("<br/>" & objnode.Name & ": " & objnode.InnerText & "<br/>")
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write("<br/>" & ex.ToString & "<br/>")

    End Try
End Su
```

Comment: Do you have any way to get the details of the remote server errors? And are you sure the URL you are trying to get is valid? From your example it doesn't seem like you are providing a valid URL.

Comment: i had to change the url because of confidentiality reason to the customer

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to make note that i was taking over this code from another developer. I found from the company that this was suppose to before that there was actually a missing querystring that was required by the service. by just adding url +="querystring=" & value it worked.